# How to use parameterless constructor with ninject di and winforms

Tags: winforms, constructor, ninject

I'm working on a WinForm application using ninject for dependency injection. My first problem was that the form being instantiated had a parameter (for DI). I added a parameterless constructor thinking this would help.  The problem now is that the code inside the constructor with the parameter gets skipped.  Here what it looks like:

On my main form:

```
private void mnuSettings_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   frmSettings objForm = new frmSettings();
   objForm.Owner=this;
   objForm.Show();
}
```

In the frmSettings form:

```
private readonly IApplicationPropertiesInterface _applicationProperties;

public frmSettings()
{
   InitializeComponent();
}

public frmSettings(IApplicationPropertiesInterface applicationProperties) : this()
{
   _applicationProperties = applicationProperties;
}
```

When I call _applicationProperties.GetExtractFileSaveLocationDirectory() it blows up because the code to set _applicationProperties was never called.

Im wondering if I have structured this incorrectly, and what the best way to achieve this is.  My goal is to call the parameterless constructor, but also set _applicationProperties.

Any assistance would be most grateful.

Comment: frmSettings objForm must be registered and resolve by container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you might be expecting that having Ninject in the building will mena that `new` will work differently to normal. It doesn't - you need to be doing a `kernel.Resolve<Something>` for the DI to kick in. Note that most of these pitfalls are covered in detail on [the wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki)

Can you edit your answer to include details of what you're doing outside of this form please?

In the meantime, here are some previous questions that overlap significantly:-

- [What is the best practice for WinForms dialogs with ninject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493932/what-is-the-best-practice-for-winforms-dialogs-with-ninject)
- [How to use Ninject in a Windows Forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129092/how-to-use-ninject-in-a-windows-forms-application)